# Data flow in computer networks

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, network-protocols

Does anyone know a book that describes what happens behind the scenes when an application open a socket, bind a port, listen for connection, establishes connections (syn, syn+ack, ack), send data (app layer down to transport, network, datalink, physical) and how is data passed from ethernet card (nic) to the application (explicit).

I'm a programmer and I really need to understand this process (even if it explains at the transistors level). All I know is that the kernel is involved and we all know that the kernel is abstract, but i want to fully understand how a program sends data.

I would be grateful if anyone can tell.

Answer (score 0):

It's a broad question, so here's a broad answer:

- UDP/IP [RFC 768](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt)
- TCP/IP [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)
- IP [RFC 791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt)
- MAC resolution [RFC 826](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc826.txt)

Comment: yes ... but the RFCs are not telling how actually software does this ... at the low-level. They are telling what should include/do

Comment: well then it gets even broader, there's dozens of implementations out there, that's the beauty of standards, you can implement what you want as long as the result is the same.  Name a kernel and we can show you the code

Comment: And a primer re OSI-layer 1 (and sometimes 2), that's most surely proprietary firmware code and I'm not aware of publicly available sources

Comment: linux kernel for example ... what's happening when an aplication create a socket and then listen for connection . the "behind the scenes" process (what writes in memory, processor registers .. etc etc)